# Returning multiple attributes query asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

In function below I am trying to return multiple attributes form multiple tables.

Parent table > Child table

AspNetUser > Ad

Ad > MobileAd

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetAd(int id)
{
    Ad add = await db.Ads.FindAsync(id);
    if (add == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    
    var ret = (from ad in db.Ads
               where ad.Id.Equals(id)
               orderby ad.time
               select new
               {
                   title = ad.title,
                   postedById = ad.AspNetUser.Id,
                   postedByName = ad.AspNetUser.UserName,
                   description = ad.description,
                   mobilead = ad.MobileAds.FirstOrDefault(x => x.adId == ad.Id),
               });
    return Ok(ret);
}
```

In ajax request to fetch data I got `Internal Server Error` and below is the figure of debugging.

[image: Debugging picture]

Why it is fetching objects instead of data?

**Updated:**

[image]

When I click on refresh icon in `Results View` during debugging. Its shows data! but not returning it.

Comment: Could you include the exception?

Comment: I didn't get exception. `Internal Server Error` is the error in console window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may consider using

```
 return Ok(ret.ToArray());
```

instead of

```
 return Ok(ret);
```

otherwise linq query above will not be evaluated.

Comment: 1. Have you see image attached in question. You can see its not returning values(data).

2.I am returning single record so there is no need to use `ToArray` 

3.I used used `ToArray` but no success. Request always go to `ajax().fail() function.

Comment: 1. Of course I have seen the attached image, but the debug line over the variable "ret" was not expanded, so could not get enough info. 2. in order to enumarate and execute a linq query, ToArray, ToList or a loop statement must be used; otherwise it only stands as a statement only.

Comment: On expand its shows `non public members` and  `results view` which I think was of no use.

Comment: there must be a refresh icon near to "results view". By clicking on it Linq query is executed and results are shown below it.

Comment: Yes! It fetched data by clicking on refresh icon. What next? why its not returning data?

Comment: I think you must now focus on the linq query now. I am suspicious about the where condition.

Comment: Its fetching right data from table so where condition is working fine. I have also tried this `where ad.Id == id`  .

Comment: Can you try .FirstOrDefault() at the end of the Linq?

Comment: Ok that worked. It returned values! but its still going to `.fail()` part of `ajax` request. On expending error XML it says `<ExceptionMessage>
The 'ObjectContent1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/json; charset=utf-8'.
</ExceptionMessage>`

Comment: You may try to narrow fields of the anonymous object returned by the query and plot the problematic field. I think one of fields may have serialization problem.

Comment: ok! I commented last line in select statement (as it was returning a mobileAd object). Now `ajax` call go to `.done() part`. which is `.done(function () {
                var mappedads = $.map(data, function (item) { return new ad(item); });
                self.ad(mappedads);
            })`
And I am getting error `Uncaught Reference Error: data is not defined` Which mean it is not receiving data??

Comment: I think that there's an ambiguity with `function ad(data)` and an object named `ad`. The problematic line calls `function ad()` which does not return an object.

Comment: yeah. sorry that's a stupid mistake. But still its not working. On second line in .done part on `self.ad(mappedads);` It says `self.ad is not defined`. but ad is defined. Can you please check this. jsfiddle.net/c4cxmhb0

Comment: No first line returns data. Why it is saying `self.ad is not defined`

Comment: Thank you for your precious time. I will try figure out myself. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: thanks for your appreciation. I wish I could help more.